“enter in my house” vs “enter my house”
From English animation Rich and poor Episode26(2:10) Sunshine English story
(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mvwwWc6hzDs)
Situation
Judy's mother was at home alone. ( the bell rang) She was upset to find Peter and Rose in front of the door because she was supposed to be missing. She didn't want them to find her. She said to herself.

"...Oh God help me. I did not lock the door. they can enter in my house. I have to lock the door. But I can not go there. They will see me. " (She ran upstairs.)

The verb enter seems to be intransitive in this sentence. So my question is:
Why "enter in my house" is preferable to "enter my house" in this situation?

"English animation" (is it a comic?)  is not the name of the source. Please tell us in your question where you read this piece. Thanks.

Sources need to be cited, and authors need to be attributed. If we see the author is a native speaker, answers may take that into account. "They can get in (the/my house)“ sounds more natural in dialogue or someone's verbal thoughts IMO

www.youtube.com/watch?v=mvwwWc6hzDs
Sunshine English story "Rich and poor "Episode26(2:10)

It appears "Sunshine English" is based in Pakistan, it is true that English is widely spoken, and it used to be the language of the government and judicial systems before Pakistan earned independence. However, the dialogue in the videos is very stilted and "wooden", and although the voice actors might be native speakers (American) they are speaking too slowly, real speech is much faster.

I didn't know that. I thought there must be a deep meaning in using " enter in "ha,ha.           Though the dialogue is emotionless, I think the stories are still interesting. Thanks.

"Enter in" is archaic English found, for example, in the King James version of the Christian Bible (1611) and literature of that period I am the door: by me if any man enter in, he shall be saved (John 10:9)

I spotted other errors in the bit I watched - 'meet to people' instead of 'meet people' and 'I don't have a car as well' instead of 'either'.  There should be a comma and a pause when he uses Rose's name at the end of a sentence.

From now on I had better watch this anime as a material to find errors in it. I came to know this anime  because Youtuber Japanese teacher in English recommended it.   But she didn't say there are lots of mistakes in its English because I think  she didn't notice those mistakes. This shows a kind of the limit of  the ability of a  English teacher who is not a native English speaker. But I know she is  still a good teacher.

@Michael Harvey Thank you sir, I will cherish the phrase " enter in " from now.

Yatterman, also 'enter into (a place)' is similarly archaic.

@Kate Bunting Thank you for your comment .

@Michael Harvey What do you mean by 'enter into (a place)' is similarly archaic. ?

@MichaelHarvey: Literal enter into [a place] is certainly at least "dated" (usually, you just enter the place). But the metaphoric usage is alive and kicking: They entered into an agreement.

@FumbleFingers - people used to 'enter into' an inheritance, but I think that is seriously obsolete, except on Bible web sites where they talk about that when they mean 'go to heaven'. You commented on the relative frequencies of 'entered upon his inheritance' and 'entered into his inheritance' on Aug 17, 2022...

I’m voting to close this question because the text being queried is very low quality English from an obviously non-native-Anglophone source.

@MichaelHarvey - Sorry, sir I skipped the words " ( a place ) " in your comment, so I didn't  understand your sentence. Now I got it. Thank you  sir.


*they can enter in my house

The example is incorrect; enter should be transitive here:
Intransitive uses like those with in are for different constructions as Cambridge Dictionary explains and illustrates:

(Level B1) to be included in a competition, race, or exam, or to arrange for someone else to do this:
be entered for/in Both men have been entered for/in the 100 metres in Paris next month.

To use the intransitive form in the OP's story, we could say

they can enter [through the door, which is unlocked]


Thanks, @Mari-Lou A. I added more details a while back.

Thanks, @Mari-Lou A, for this detailing.  Okay, so we need to include words like ‘Cambridge Dictionary sense B1’ in answers when we cite a source from there rather than just embedding the link in words.
